# Python sort (json) list by calculated value

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have originally a JSON format with products and the challenge is to sort this list by the best price per unit (prdata3, prdata2, prdata1):

```
{'prdata3': {'variation': 'stand', 'price': '78 54', 'amount': '6', 
      'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/3'}, 
 'prdata2': {'variation': 'stand', 'price': '15 24', 'amount': '1', 
      'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/2'}, 
 'prdata1': {'variation': 'vc', 'price': '78 54', 'amount': '12', 
      'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/1'}}
```

The price needs to be divided by the amount and the list needs to be sorted by this value, so in my example the output need to be (prdata1 (6,55), prdata3 (13,09), prdata2 (15,24)):

```
{'prdata1': {'variation': 'vc', 'price': '78 54', 'amount': '12', 'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/1'}, 'prdata3': {'variation': 'stand', 'price': '78 54', 'amount': '6', 'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/3'}, 'prdata2': {'variation': 'stand', 'price': '15 24', 'amount': '1', 'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/2'}}
```

What is the best strategy here? I gave my best to first go in there with "for each", looking for the price, replace the space with a dot, divide it with the amount and now use this result to sort my list with something like: `sorted(mylist.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])` ... but my result as key, right?

Comment: Why `'price': '78 54'`? What do you mean by that? Is it `78.54` or `7854` or something  else? Please clarify.

Comment: Ah yes, it's 78.54 -> sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort a dictionary, as dictionary have no order.

But you can do the following:

```
print sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x:float(x[1]['price'])/int(x[1]['amount']))
```

Output:

```
[('prdata1', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/1', 'price': '78.54', 'amount': '12', 'variation': 'vc'}), 
('prdata3', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/3', 'price': '78.54', 'amount': '6', 'variation': 'stand'}), 
('prdata2', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/2', 'price': '15.24', 'amount': '1', 'variation': 'stand'})]
```

And, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` to retain the dictionary structure if it really matters.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x:float(x[1]['price'])/int(x[1]['amount'])))
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('prdata1', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/1', 'price': '78.54', 'amount': '12', 'variation': 'vc'}), 
('prdata3', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/3', 'price': '78.54', 'amount': '6', 'variation': 'stand'}), 
('prdata2', {'url': 'https://www.productwebaddress.com/2', 'price': '15.24', 'amount': '1', 'variation': 'stand'})])
```

Comment: Yeah! Very nice, i just had to replace the space with a dot and it worked!!! Oh man, that was my last 48 hours of sweat and tears, i love you! Thank you so much. =)

Comment: Glad to know it helps you. If you feel the answer satisfies the question, you could consider accepting (Press the ✓ sign ) it.  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Oh, yeah - i already thought that must be possible for me somehow. You got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I would be nice if you could show us a code snippet, so we can look it over and see where you could be stuck.

This might be a one liner, because of the clear specification, it would be something like (pseudo code, won't run):

`sorted(data, key=lambda x: float(x['price'].replace(' ', '.')) / int(x['amount']))`

I hope this helps, but if it doesn't, please provide some of your code.

Comment: Thank you as well, Ahsanul's answer is a bit more detailed -> but this goes in the same direction, so thanks! :)

Comment: My code wasn't meant to run, I was just trying to point the asker in a general direction. I will note in my answer that is more of a pseudo code.

Comment: My code wasn't intended to run, I just wanted to give a general direction what needs to be done. I will note in my answer that is more of a pseudo code.